Transform 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates based on 2D camera angle view (matplotlib camera angle)
I have a 3D plot of points and lines connecting the points in matplotlib. I'm using the ax.view_init(elev, azim, roll) function to rotate the camera. The resulting camera angles I will be using always result in a 2D view of the 3D plot. Is there a way to transform the 3D coordinates of this 2D view into new 2D coordinates that I can use to generate an identical 2D plot? Note that the camera angles can differ, but will always result in a 2D view in my use case.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Plot points
ax.scatter(points['X'], points['Y'], points['Z'], marker='o', color='blue', label='Points')

# Plotting lines between points
for index, row in lines_df.iterrows():
    point_a = points[points['Point'] == row['Point A']]
    point_b = points[points['Point'] == row['Pode B']]

    ax.plot([point_a['X'].values[0], point_b['X'].values[0]],
            [point_a['Y'].values[0], point_b['Y'].values[0]],
            [point_a['Z'].values[0], point_b['Z'].values[0]],
            color='black', linewidth=1)

#Example of camera angles which result in a 2D view.
ax.view_init(elev=-90, azim=90, roll=0)



Points is a dataframe with columns [Point, X, Y, Z]
lines_df is a dataframe with columns [Line, Point A, Point B]

there are MANY undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
